# RewriteRule for page handling giving the target page name instead of request

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule api/v2/([^/]+)/?$ api/v2/api.php?request=$1 [L]
RewriteRule api/v2 api/v2/api.php [L]
RewriteRule ^$ handler.php?request=main [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?request=$1 [L]
```

...in my .htaccess file in the root directory. Its intent is to rewrite `https://example.org/hello/world` with `https://example.org/handler.php?request=hello/world`.
Whenever I navigate to an existing directory, it adds `?request` to the end. For example: if I navigate to `https://example.org/foo` (foo being a directory), it'll redirect to `https://example.org/foo/?request=foo`.
Why does this happen and how can I fix it?

**Update 1**
I added the following lines, which work as they need:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

But this has caused another problem, when I go to handler.php and echo `$_GET["request"]`, I get `handler.php`.
**Update 2**
I've shortened the `.htaccess` to just this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?request=$1 [L]
```

But still have the same issue, `$_GET["request"]` returns `handler.php`
**Update 3**
I've added a bounty to this question, more out of curiosity than anything now.

Comment: Probably you need to add one more `RewriteRule` for 'appending slash if not' before rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?request=$1 [L]`.

Comment: Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your rule is rewriting the request in loop mode rewriting the destination file **handler.php** to itself due to the unconditional rule and catch-all pattern.

You need to fix the pattern of your rule so it doesn't match the destination file.

```
rewrite engine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^((?!handler.php).*)$ handler.php?request=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you so much. -CM

Answer (score 1):

I would use it in the opposite approach.
If the requested file **isn't** an existing file or directory **then** set a rewriterule to the handler file with the request.

Tested the following code and it seems to work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handler.php?request=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**handler.php**

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

http://localhost/hello/world

Output:

```
array(1) { ["request"]=> string(11) "hello/world" }
```

---

http://localhost/example (does exist)

Output:

```
Directory parent
```

---

http://localhost/a.php (does exist)

Output:

```
File a exists //Something that is written in a.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not want it to load existing files/directories. I wish for everything to run through handler.php while giving me the request in the provided `GET` parameter.

**Edit**
The question's been answered, but +1 because it might be useful for others in the future.

Thanks! -CM